# Teams Bot: User logged event

Tags: authentication, events, microsoft-teams

I have a Teams node js bot, and I would like to know when a user has just logged in Teams client, to send a message to him. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Comment: Please take a look at [send proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can send proactive messages, but i need to know when a user is just logged in Teams client, to do things... If it is possible... Maybe I didn't explain my problem properly. Or the response is in your link?

Comment: Please provide more information what you actually you are looking for.

Comment: I would like to know in my bot when a user logs in Teams client, if possible. Not when the user sends me a message (onMessage), or the user is added to a channel (onMembersAdded)

Comment: You can capture the OnMessageActivityAsync event while logging  in and send the message.Please take a look at [send Welcome messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).